# Creating a Network interface/adapter from an ip and port

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

Is it possible to create a Network interface/adapter from ip 127.0.0.1 and port 8580 in Windows?

The goal is sharing the Internet that is on 127.0.0.1 with another interface.

Many VPNs like Freegate or Psiphone don't have an Adaptor, they use loopback ip.

Comment: Not an answer, but note that Win8.1 has reached end of support. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-81 It will no longer receive security updates, non-security updates, bug fixes et cetera.

Comment: Again, not an  answer, but Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en) and other Linux distros *do* provide that capability. You could try running from Live Linux from USB to create a hotspot. These OS's *can* be updated as needed.